# IGrouping and Casting in Linq

Tags: linq, casting, grouping

I have the following query:

```
var groupCats =
            from g in groups
            group g by g.Value into grouped
            select new
            {
                GroupCategory = grouped.Key,
                Categories = GetCategories(grouped.Key, child)
            };
```

This works fine.  In the anonymous type returned GroupCategory is a string, and Categories are an Enumerable - what is the proper way to declare this instead of using 'var'?

I tried:

```
IGrouping<string,string> groupCats =
            from g in groups
            group g by g.Value into grouped
            select new
            {
                GroupCategory = grouped.Key,
                Categories = GetCategories(grouped.Key, child)
            };
```

and

```
IGrouping<string,Enumerable<string>> groupCats =
            from g in groups
            group g by g.Value into grouped
            select new
            {
                GroupCategory = grouped.Key,
                Categories = GetCategories(grouped.Key, child)
            };
```

In both instances I get:

Cannot implicity convert type....An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)

How do I cast this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have to use `var` because you have an anonymous type. This situation is in fact why it was necessary to add `var` to the language. If you want to write an explicit type instead of `var` then you have to select a concrete class which must be defined somewhere. Then your code can look like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> groupCats =
    from g in groups
    group g by g.Value into grouped
    select new MyClass
    {
        GroupCategory = grouped.Key,
        Categories = GetCategories(grouped.Key, child)
    };
```

I suspect though that the above query is not correct. You perform a grouping but then you only use `grouped.Key`.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to define a concrete type for this. The `select new` statement is going to return an anonymous type, so you're going to have an enumerable of the anonymous type. If you want something else, you would define a class and then use `select new MyClass` instead, giving you an IEnumerable of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

You might write a query like this:

```
from g in groups 
group g by g.Value
```

In that case, the type is

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<KeyType, GType>> groupCats =
```

Comment: So the type would be: IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,IEnumerable<string>>>  ?

which still gives me the invalid cast exception.  So I still need a concrete class implementation as indicated in the other answers?

Comment: No, the type would be IEnumerable<CompilerNamedType>, but you can't use CompilerNamedType before the compiler names it, so you have to use var.